# Superview of UIViewController's root UIView is nil?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to ios programming so please bear with me:

In the process of trying to familiarize myself with the `ios` api, I'm trying to redo a storyboard/xib project programmatically, however I am running into some issues with autolayout constraints.

The project defined some constraint relationships between what I assume to be the the root `UIView` of the `UIViewController` and its `superview` like so:

[image: view hierarchy]

However, `view.superview` returns `nil` when I try to reference it in my `autolayout` code in `viewDidLoad()`.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244040/what-if-a-uiview-has-no-superview-what-does-its-frame-property-become), all UIViews have superviews (at the very least, a UIWindow) so this shouldn't be the case? Am I misunderstanding something, or can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

viewDidLoad is invoked when the view controller has loaded its view. If you are trying to reference your view in the autolayout module before its parentController view has loaded its view then view.superview will be nil.
I can elaborate more if I can see the autolayout code of yours.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I get `nil` just by calling `print("view.superview! \(view.superview!)")` in `viewDidLoad()`